# Trying to figure out why Firefox is sending unsolicited FIN ACK packets

Tags: javascript, firefox, networking, tcp

I have written an application in DHTML using OpenLaszlo.  The application works perfectly fine in Chrome, but it is having problems in Firefox.  The javascript client makes HTTP POST requests to a Struts2 middle layer, which queries the database via Hibernate and then returns an XML response.  The application is in production, so the client code, middle layer and database are all hosted on my desktop machine.

I can literally run the application in Chrome and Firefox side-by-side, and while everything works perfectly in Chrome, a few of the HTTP requests (the same ones every time) will fail on Firefox.  The ones that fail do so immediately after the POST request is initiated, with no HTTP response or error code given (I am using Firebug to watch the POST requests and responses).

After watching the traffic with Wireshark I have determined that, for some reason, Firefox is sending a FIN ACK packet immediately (less than a second) after making the POST request and receiving the standard ACK from the server.

The network traffic looks like this:

In Chrome: Client sends POST -> Server sends ACK -> Server sends XML data -> Client sends ACK -> Server sends HTTP/XML 200 Response -> Client sends ACK

In Firefox: Client sends POST -> Server sends ACK -> Client sends FIN, ACK -> Server sends ACK -> Server sends XML data -> Client sends a reset

I am wondering if anyone has witnessed this type of behavior before, and might know what I can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i also encountered this issue.  Firefox send FIN,ACK related to its new network change feature. see: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/0a066b7ffa46

we spend huge time in checking this. 
i have also an post at stackoverflow: [when firefox 38 sent FIN,ACK after server ack an http get from firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086868/when-firefox-38-sent-fin-ack-after-server-ack-an-http-get-from-firefox)

for anyone interested in this, please track: bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245059 workaround solution is to set "network.http.network-changed.timeout” setting bigger. check our reported firefox bug for more detail.