# when firefox 38 sent FIN,ACK after server ack an http get from firefox?

Tags: firefox, wireshark, tcp

[image: wireshark snapshot]
see attached wireshark log:(pls click it to make it bigger enough for view):

- in packet 37 , client sent a http get to server
- in packet 38 , server response ack
- in packet 39, after client wait 5 seconds, client sent  a [FIN,ACK]

client is a Firefox 38 on a win 7 system.

my question is:
why client sent a FIN,ACK after 5 seconds?

It is because after wait 5 seconds, nothing come from server? 
if my guess true, is there any setting in Firefox to extend this, as server is slow and 5 seconds is short.

if not true, is it just because client (firefox browser )has some issue which cause client to sent FIN ,ACK to close connection?
OR could be some server issue? 
OR firefox issue?

we encounter this issue intermittently when server performance is slow. Server people say it is not a server issue, and client people say it is not application client issue?

Could it be possible just firefox issue, or some extension on firefox cause client sent  FIN,ACK?

the most important question:

1. from the wireshark, it is reasonable that server people say no problem at server because client issued a fin,ack?
2. Is there any firefox setting to change this behavior?

thanks in advance for anybody who knows TCP/IP.

Comment: The word in this context is 'packet', not 'package'.

Comment: thanks for correction

Comment: seems a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381405/trying-to-figure-out-why-firefox-is-sending-unsolicited-fin-ack-packets

Comment: root cause found, it is related to an Firefox issue, for anyone interested in this, please track: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245059  workaround solution is to set "network.http.network-changed.timeout” setting bigger. check our reported firefox bug for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it reasonable that server people say no problem at server because client issued a fin,ack?

Yes. Firefox decided to close the connection after a five-second idle timeout. It's normal.

> Is there any firefox setting to change this behavior?

That's off-topic here, but why? It seems like a good idle timeout value to me.

Comment: thanks for check this.      about " five-second idle timeout. It's normal.", do you mean it's normal for firefox to close the connection after " five-second idle timeout" . but you also said that "Yes",mean "server has no problem"?          If both firefox and server has no issue, where is the issue?    I need to know the setting to understand this better, whether it is a firefox setting or special setting on tcp/ip.    thanks in advance

Comment: When I say 'it's normal' after a sentence stating that Firefox closed the connection after a five-second timeout, I mean 'it's normal'. When I say 'yes' to a question asking me whether it is reasonable for your server people to say there is no problem, I mean 'yes'. There is no issue here. It's normal. If you want to fiddle about with it for no apparent reason, see [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1042479), which I found by typing 'Firefox connection timeout setting' into Google. I feel you could probably have accomplished that yourself.

Comment: thanks , i tried google a lot  , there are so many different kinds of timeout. and trying each, didn't finish yet.  will also check this one .

Comment: There is only one Firefox connection timeout setting, and the result I linked to was very near the top.

Comment: hi EJP, http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.typeaheadfind.enabletimeout did you mean this. but this seems  related to find text related, not connection time out.  more background, i am investigate this because, trying to find a way that not let firefox to fire [FIN,ACK] or let it only fire after 5 minutes , instead of 5 seconds.     we have an intermittent issue, server people get the wireshark log and think the problem is in client, while client people can't find why this [FIN,ACK] is sent.

Comment: root cause found, it is related to an Firefox issue, for anyone interested in this, please track: bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245059 workaround solution is to set "network.http.network-changed.timeout” setting bigger. check our reported firefox bug for more detail